# Do something after a DELETE request is complete with Angular HttpClient

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a button which deletes an item on click. I want to show a simple `alert('Item deleted')` alert after the action is done. However I can't seem to make it work. Note that the item gets deleted.

Here's what I tried:

**deleteItem** function in my component

```
deleteItem(id: number) {
    this.eventsService
      .deleteEventById(id)
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => alert('Item deleted')
      );
  }
```

Nothing is printed to the console and no alert is shown.

**deleteEventById** function in my service

```
deleteEventById(id: number) {
  return this.http
    .delete(`/api/events/${id}`, this.headerForPrivateCalls)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
}
```

**api route** (if it matters)

```
router.delete('/events/:id', authCheck, (req, res) => {
    connection((client) => {
        client.db('gordes').collection('events')
        .deleteOne({id: +req.params.id})
        .then(() => {
            res.status(204);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            sendError(err, res);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: DId you try debugging (breakpoints/step by step/network tab) to make sure the http call is made?

Comment: Yes, the item gets deleted successfully, however I want to show a message exactly after it is deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You don't seem to return any body from your backend server, but just a status. So your console.log should only print a blank string

Comment: I changed the API to return `.then((done) => {res.json(done); })`. Still nothing. It doesn't even print a blank string, it prints nothing at all

Comment: Sorry, just checking: do any of your other console.log show ? FYI, the complete callback (your alert) will not be called if there is any error (so it'll only be called when the success callback is triggered). But's it's probably not the problem here if you see absolutely no console log message

Comment: And which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @David None of the three are showing, and I'm using Angular 5, with the CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your deleteEventById service does not return anything to the Observable.
You will need to add a .map()

```
    deleteEventById(id: number) {
       return (this.http
        .delete(`/api/events/${id}`, this.headerForPrivateCalls)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .pipe(
           catchError(this.handleError),
        );
      )
   }
```

**EDIT**

the problem seems to be in the node back-end :

you dont return anything by

```
res.status(204);
```

use :

```
res.status(204).send();
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm using HttpClient, which got rid of map and instead does it automatically.

Comment: ah! now that I see it you dont return anything from the node back-end. 
        res.status(204);
should be res.send({}).status(204);

Comment: Yes, that worked but it was only  half of the problem. I also needed a subscription in my component to attach to. When I made a response and changed the function to `this.mySub = this.eventsService.delete...` it was up and running.